# Haskell: Subsequences of a String

Tags: string, haskell

I'm new to Haskell and I found some examples to practice, but no idea how to deal with them.
I need to split `"abcd"` into subsequences.

to:

```
["",a,b,c,d,ab,ac,ad,bc,bd,cd,abc,abd,bcd,acd,abcd]
```

What i found is that I have to use subsequences function.

```
subsequences :: [a] -> [[a]]
```

How should I proceed?

Comment: Yep I know that.. but this make the result not like the shown above.. and I thing I have to do something else but not shown int the chapter where I read..

Comment: Just need to get string and write the subsequences it to a certain format.. i'm begginer :)

Comment: A simple way could be (aproximation!) `sortBy (compare ´on´ length) $ subsequences "abcd"` but try your self a direct way...

Comment: are you sure the sequence ends with `...,bcd,acd,abcd]` and not `...,acd,bcd,abcd]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do that with `subsequences` as suggested take a look at the example:

```
import Data.List

subsequences "abcd"
```

**Output:**

```
["","a","b","ab","c","ac","bc","abc","d","ad","bd","abd","cd","acd","bcd","abcd"]
```

**Note:** `subsequences` doesn't sort the output. But, if you want the sorted output you can use the following:

```
import Data.List
import Data.Function

sortBy (compare `on` length) $ subsequences "abcd"
```

**OR**

```
import Data.List 
import GHC.Exts

sortWith length $ subsequences "abcd"
```

**Output:**

```
["","a","b","c","d","ab","ac","bc","ad","bd","cd","abc","abd","acd","bcd","abcd"]
```

Check here for more information:

- [Data.List.subsequences](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:subsequences)

Comment: yep this is what i do, but I need to get this output: ["",a,b,c,d,ab,ac,ad,bc,bd,cd,abc,abd,bcd,acd,abcd]

Comment: @user2497254 Updated the answer to include sorting method.

Comment: Parse error: naked expression at top level
Failed, modules loaded: none.
Prelude>
what is the problem with that?

Comment: @user2497254 I tried my code samples again and it works. It has to be related to the rest of your code.

Comment: this is the whole task.. no rest code :) Like I told you I'm beginner and stuck on this chapter with subsequences

Comment: Let's debug it then shall we? :) First open `ghci` and try copy pasting the code line by line and let me know if there is a problem there.

Comment: hmm no problem with debug... I tried the code to a .hs file and run it

Comment: @user2497254 You can't have a "naked expression at top level" in a .hs file. Turn it into a definition like ``sortedSubsequences = sortBy (compare `on` length) . subsequences``, load the file in ghci and test with `sortedSubsequences "abcd"`.

Comment: `sortWith length . subsequences`

Comment: Why not monads? `filterM (const [True,False]) "abcd"`

Comment: @JohannesKuhn I didn't want to confuse the OP since he said he's new to Haskell.

Comment: There is just more than one way to do it: `[a] -> [[a]]`

Comment: @JohannesKuhn I concur.

Answer (score 2):

It is a simple recursive task.

Suppose, you have a list of subsequences for a sub-list. How do you produce the list of subsequences of a longer list?

I propose the list of subsequences is split into lists of subsequences by their length. So you have `[[subsequences length 0],[subsequences length 1],...]`. Easy to see that it is possible to produce longer subsequences by appending one element to the shorter subsequences: `[[subsequences length 0],[subsequences length 0 plus one element]++[subsequences length 1],[subsequences length 1 plus one element]++[subsequences length 2],...]`.

To align lists of subsequences of different lengths, add an empty list to the list of subsequences. Then append one element to the shorter subsequences, and concat with the list of longer subsequences.

```
addoneall x xs = zipWith ((++) . (map (x:))) ([]:xs) (xs ++ [[]])
```

Now

```
subsequences = concat . foldr addoneall [[[]]]
```

produces a list of subsequences of all lengths - `foldr` produces a list of subsequences by appending one element to the list of subsequences for a shorter input. Then `concat` joins the list of subsequences of different lengths into one.

```
Prelude Data.List> subsequences "abcd"
["","a","b","c","d","ab","ac","ad","bc","bd","cd","abc","abd","acd","bcd","abcd"]
```